# Can I use export to CSV functionality from web page on my mobile browser?

Tags: php, csv, mobile, export-to-csv

I've created a web page that has an "Export to CSV" button which takes table data from that same page and converts to CSV, prompts user to download and it works just fine via desktop.

I want to do the same when viewing page on mobile and it does not work.

I'm fairly new to working in mobile for the most part, so this is more of a "is it even possible it will work in mobile" type of question before I even post code.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I'm using two jQuery plugins - tableExport.js and FileSaver.js

Comment: Yes, theoretically you should be able to achieve that. What headers are you currently sending?

Comment: "and it does not work". Which part of the program is not working?

Comment: @Don'tPanic - I'm using a jquery plugin (file is titled "tableExport.js)

Comment: @JeroenHeier - When I click on the button within my Android browser, which calls a jquery plugin, I get nothing. On desktop FireFox browser it brings up prompt to save or open the csv to my Windows 10 OS.